# How do I export a MySQL database from PHPMyAdmin and import it to SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I would like to export a database from PHPMyAdmin (or MySQl Workbench) and import it to a SQLite database so that I can do local editing and testing without screwing up the live version.  I am very new to SQL, so all of the export options, etc, are rather dense to me at this point.  I have tried using the default export settings PHPMyAdmin with the command

```
sqlite3 test_db.db < maindb.sql
```

as well as

```
sqlite3--> .read maindb.sql
```

But these throw a bunch of syntax errors and 'no such table' errors.

I have also tried the oft-cited script [script found here](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776/), but when I try to run this using an export from MySQL Workbench, using the command:

```
943776/mysql2sqlite.sh maindb.sql | sqlite3 test_db.sqlite
```

I get the following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

Am I not configuring the exports correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see that the referenced script connects to the database server itself. It does **not** expect a dump!

```
./mysql2sqlite -h example.com -u root -pMySecretPassWord myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

This is the way the script should be executed. With host, username, passwort and the mysql database you would like to dump.

Since database dumps and DBMS features can be severely different between different DBMS (like MySQL and sqlite3), I would recommend to install a local MySQL server instead of using sqlite3. What advantage have you achieved when you make changes to sqlite3, which you cannot apply to the MySQL production database without changes?

Comment: How do I create a local MySQL server based on my current database?

Comment: [Install a local MySQL server.](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) [Export the whole database with MySQL Workbench from production server.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-data-export.html) [Import it into your local MySQL server.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-data-import-restore.html)

Comment: I already have the program in the first link installed, and have previously used Workbench to export the database, but it is actual setup of the local server that I am confused about.  Frankly, I don't know where to start with that.

Comment: You can read how this works for example [here](http://www.ricocheting.com/how-to-install-on-windows/mysql). If you have installed and started the mysql server correctly, you can enter `localhost`, `root`, and the password you set during installation into MySQL Workbench to connect with your local installation instead of the remote production server.

Comment: Okay, I have a local server up and running now (had some installation issues to iron out).  Now, when I export then try to import into the local db, I get the error: `ERROR 2017 (HY000): Can't open named pipe to host: .  pipe: MySQL (2)`

Comment: That is a weird error. Have you entered "localhost" for your hostname? Then try "127.0.0.1" instead.

Comment: I changed my connection type from 'Local Host/Socket' to 'Standard', and replaced 127.0.0.1 in the hostname with 'localhost'.  That appears to have fixed it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to export an sql dump of your database and then import it back into [phpLiteAdmin](https://www.phpliteadmin.org). From there you can manage your sqlite database inside your browser. When you want to export it, just open the folder where the database is stored and copy the database file.

This solution does not require messing around with scripts, and it's especially handy if you're on a Mac and you're using [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/), since phpLiteAdmin comes preinstalled with it.